# Looping a block of markup with Nunjucks

Tags: html, twig, nunjucks

I’m building static HTML templates and would like to loop over a block of markup to output it multiple times. Twig has a simple method for it, but I've been unable to find the equivalent in Nunjucks.

Twig input:

```
{% for i in 1..2 %}
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
{% endfor %}
```

HTML output:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Use the [`range`](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#range-start-stop-step) function

Comment: @DarkBee Amazing, thank you!